# Neural Network sigmoid function

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm trying to make a neural network and I have a couple of questions:

My sigmoid function is like some

```
s = 1/(1+(2.7183**(-self.values)))
if s > self.weight:
        self.value = 1
    else:
        self.value = 0
```

The self.values is a array of the connected nodes, for instance the **HNs(hidden nodes) in the HL(hidden layer) 1** is connected to all input nodes, so it's self.values is sum(inputnodes.values).

The **HNs in the HL2** is connected to all HNs in HL1, and it's self.values is sum(HL.values)

The problem is, every node is getting the value of 1, no mather their weights(unless it's too high, like 0.90~0.99)

My Neural Network is set like so:

(inputs, num_hidden_layers, num_hidden_nodes_per_layer, num_output_nodes)
inputs is a list of binary values:

Here's a log that shows this behavior.

```
>>NeuralNetwork([1,0,1,1,1,0,0],3,3,1)# 3 layers, 3 nodes each, 1 output
Layer1
Node: y1 Sum: 4, Sigmoid: 0.98, Weight: 0.10, self.value: 1
Node: y2 Sum: 4, Sigmoid: 0.98, Weight: 0.59, self.value: 1
Node: y3 Sum: 4, Sigmoid: 0.98, Weight: 0.74, self.value: 1
Layer2
Node: y1 Sum: 3, Sigmoid: 0.95, Weight: 0.30, self.value: 1
Node: y2 Sum: 3, Sigmoid: 0.95, Weight: 0.37, self.value: 1
Node: y3 Sum: 3, Sigmoid: 0.95, Weight: 0.80, self.value: 1
Layer3
Node: y1 Sum: 3, Sigmoid: 0.95, Weight: 0.70, self.value: 1
Node: y2 Sum: 3, Sigmoid: 0.95, Weight: 0.56, self.value: 1
Node: y3 Sum: 3, Sigmoid: 0.95, Weight: 0.28, self.value: 1
```

Even if I try using float points in the input it turns out the same:

```
>>NeuralNetwork([0.64, 0.57, 0.59, 0.87, 0.56],3,3,1)
Layer1
Node: y1 Sum: 3.23, Sigmoid: 0.96, Weight: 0.77, self.value: 1
Node: y2 Sum: 3.23, Sigmoid: 0.96, Weight: 0.45, self.value: 1
Node: y3 Sum: 3.23, Sigmoid: 0.96, Weight: 0.83, self.value: 1
Layer2
Node: y1 Sum: 3, Sigmoid: 0.95, Weight: 0.26, self.value: 1
Node: y2 Sum: 3, Sigmoid: 0.95, Weight: 0.39, self.value: 1
Node: y3 Sum: 3, Sigmoid: 0.95, Weight: 0.53, self.value: 1
Layer3
Node: y1 Sum: 3, Sigmoid: 0.95, Weight: 0.43, self.value: 1
Node: y2 Sum: 3, Sigmoid: 0.95, Weight: 0.52, self.value: 1
Node: y3 Sum: 3, Sigmoid: 0.95, Weight: 0.96, self.value: 0
```

Note de Node y3 in the layer3, the only one that returned a 0 after the sigmoid

What am I doing wrong?

Also, is it really necessary to connect every node with every other node in the previous layer? Isn't it better to let it be random?

EDIT:
Forgot to mention, this is a in-development NN, I'll be using a genetic algorithm to train the network.

EDIT2:

```
class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, inputs, num_hidden_layers, num_hidden_nodes_per_layer, num_output):
        self.input_nodes = inputs
        self.num_inputs = len(inputs)
        self.num_hidden_layers = num_hidden_layers
        self.num_hidden_nodes_per_layer = num_hidden_nodes_per_layer
        self.num_output = num_output

        self.createNodes()
        self.weights = self.getWeights()
        self.connectNodes()
        self.updateNodes()

    def createNodes(self):
        self._input_nodes = []
        for i, v in enumerate(self.input_nodes):
            node = InputNode("x"+str(i+1),v)
            self._input_nodes.append(node)

        self._hidden_layers = []
        for n in xrange(self.num_hidden_layers):
            layer = HiddenLayer("Layer"+str(n+1),self.num_hidden_nodes_per_layer)
            self._hidden_layers.append(layer)

    def getWeights(self):
        weights = []
        for node in self._input_nodes:
            weights.append(node.weight)

        for layer in self._hidden_layers:
            for node in layer.hidden_nodes:
                weights.append(node.weight)
        return weights

    def connectNodes(self):
        for i,layer in enumerate(self._hidden_layers):
            for hidden_node in layer.hidden_nodes:
                if i == 0:
                    for input_node in self._input_nodes:
                        hidden_node.connections.append(input_node)
                else:
                    for previous_node in self._hidden_layers[i-1].hidden_nodes:
                            hidden_node.connections.append(previous_node)

    def updateNodes(self):
        for layer in self._hidden_layers:
            for node in layer.hidden_nodes:
                node.updateValue()
```

And here's the updateValue() method of the nodes:

```
def updateValue(self):
    value = 0
    for node in self.connections:
        value += node.value
    self.sigmoid(value) # the function at the beginning of the question.
```

The nodes created just have value, name, and weight(random at start).

Comment: Please post your implementation of `NeuralNetwork`.

Comment: It looks like you're not weighting the individual inputs to each node. Also, you don't typically threshold the hidden layer outputs (that I'm aware of), although I'm not sure how it'll change things when training with a GA.

Comment: Oh damn... I've been bashing my head in this for a couple of hours and all because I forgot this small detail.

Comment: @AMacK, I thought that the neurons act like all-or-nothing case, thus the threshold.

Comment: whats the difference between `self.value` and `self.values`?

Comment: self.value is the value of a node, 0 or 1 after the threshold, self.values are a list of the value of the connected nodes. eg: HiddenNode1 of the Layer 1 is connected to Input1,Input2 and Input3. the self.values are [Input1.value,Input2.value,Input3.value], after the sigmoid function it can be either 1 or 0 depending on the self.values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mashing together several different NN concepts.

The logistic function (which is the generalized form of the sigmoid) already serves as a threshold. Specifically, it is a differentiable threshold which is essential for the backpropagation learning algorithm. So you don't need that piecewise threshold function (if statement).

The weights are analogues for synaptic strength and are applied during summation (or feedforward propagation). So each connection between a pair of nodes has a weight that is multiplied by the sending node's activation level (the output of the threshold function).

Finally, even with these changes, a fully-connected neural network with all positive weights will probably still produce all 1's for the output. You can either include  negative weights corresponding to inhibitory nodes, or reduce connectivity significantly (e.g. with a 0.1 probability that a node in layer n connects to a node in layer n+1).

Comment: That's what happens when you don't have any background in computer science and tries to self learn this with a bunch of different methods. Thanks, I'll try to fix those problems. I have another simple question, how many weights does a 3 inputs, 3 layers with 5 hidden nodes and 1 output have? The way I'm doing is 19 one for each noed(input,hidden and output). But I guess that might be wrong too.

Comment: A fully connected network with 3 inputs, 3 layers of 5 nodes each, and 1 output would have 15 + 25 + 25 + 5 = 70 weights total, and these should probably vary randomly from -1 to 1 before training.